# Manipulating RingCentral settings via API - Agent Skill Proficiencies

Tags: ringcentral

Good Evening,

For those skilled with RingCentral API calls, is it possible to manipulate many of the user selectable options via their web/browser portal?   My company uses HubSpot for our CRM and I can change (almost to the minute detail) every part of our day-to-day use via an external app and API calls.  For RingCentral I'd like to be able to do the same; specifically change agent skill proficiencies via an app. (which would be based on time of day)   Does RC allow this level of control?

I have not tried anything yet short of browsing RingCentral's API/developer website.